# Выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, меню, html

Добрый день. Прошу помощи 
Есть два выпадающих меню. Нужно, чтоб при выборе из первого меню одной строки блокировалась вторая выпадающая менюшка.

Если выбрать Секционные, Сдвижные или Рольставни, то выпадающее меню "Открывать" блокировалась...

Сказали как то через jquery change и disabled сделать... Но я в jq полный ноль :)

```
<div class="control-group"> 
<div class="control-label">Тип ворот</div> 
<div class="controls"><select name=razmer5>
<option>Секционные</option>
<option>Сдвижные</option>
<option>Распашные</option>
<option>Рольставни</option>
</select>
</div></div>

<div class="control-group"> 
<div class="control-label">Открывать</div> 
<div class="controls"><select name=razmer6>
<option>Внутрь</option>
<option>Наружу</option>
</select>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Это я просто скопировал текст из файла шаблона .tpl. У меня он тоже работает, если bp txt сделать html...

Comment: Ну этот код работает, но не так)) вторая менюшка теперь всегда заблокирована...

Comment: Ох, только что проверил еще раз. Все работает как надо. Проверяйте, как подключили этот код к себе. Готовая страничка: http://rghost.ru/50937130

Comment: Да, так все работает. Но почему то на самом сайте, вторая менюшка всегда заблокирована...

Comment: Если все подключено точно так же, как в файле, то все будет работать.  
1) Проверьте отсутствие ошибок в консоли браузера  
2) Проверьте, загружается ли у вас библиотека jQuery  
3) Проверьте, есть ли вызов функции на событии onchange у первого select (последние 4 строки моего ответа)

Comment: Ну дык, Вы верстку поменяли и имя элемента уже не razmer6, а razmer4.  
Замените **select = $("select[name='razmer6']");**  
На  **select = $("select[name='razmer4']");**  
И будет вам счастье...

Answer (score 4):

Рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/P4n44/2/)**

--*Доработал ответ, учитывая комментарии задавшего вопрос. Данный код полностью рабочий в состоянии "как есть".*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pleaseSwitch(obj) {
        var gate_type = $(obj).val(),
        select = $("select[name='razmer4']");
        if (gate_type === 'Распашные') {
            select.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            select.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">Тип ворот</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="razmer5" onchange="pleaseSwitch(this);">
            <option>Секционные</option>
            <option>Сдвижные</option>
            <option>Распашные</option>
            <option>Рольставни</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">Открывать</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="razmer4" disabled>
            <option>Внутрь</option>
            <option>Наружу</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Обратите особое внимание на эти две строчки:

```
<select name="razmer4" disabled>
```

и

```
<select name="razmer5" onchange="pleaseSwitch(this);">
```

Comment: Извиняюсь... Но как это подключать? :)

Comment: @bucha, в тэге head сначала подключаешь сам JQuery. Например, с официального сайта:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
А ниже, в другой тэг script, вставляешь приведенный ниже код.

Comment: http://rghost.ru/private/50935584/8ce9b567ef126192b10434978fa72468

так сделал, не получается :(
и на сайте для этих менюшек прописан стиль, может из-за этого еще?...

Comment: @bucha, второй тэг скрипт, в котором содержится код, тоже должен находится в тэге head

Comment: Если так, то тоже не работает... :(

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='razmer5']").change(function () {
        var gate_type = $(this).val(),
            select = $("select[name='razmer4']");
        if (gate_type === 'Распашные') {
            select.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            select.prop('disabled', 'disabled');        
        }
    });
});
  </script>
</head>

Comment: @bucha, у меня все работает. У вас файл с расширением .txt, попробуйте переименовать в index.html, например.

Comment: @bucha, я обновил свой ответ. Пожалуйста, изучите основы html и вопросов по подключению возникать не будет.